# Huawei Maps: MapsInitializer is not initialized

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit

I have a trouble to implement Huawei maps even after I implemented Google Maps, OsmDroid and Mapsforge before. The error I see is:

> HmsMapKit_MapView_15    MapsInitializer is not initialized.

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465638/hms-map-kit-is-not-rendering) didn't solve the problem and I need to find what is wrong.

I even tried to copy the full Activity code from a demo sample:

```
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MapViewDemoActivity"
        private const val MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE = 100
        private val LAT_LNG = LatLng(48.893478, 2.334595)
        private val RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

        /**
         * checkSelfPermission
         *
         * @param context     Context
         * @param permissions permissions
         * @return true or false
         */
        private fun hasPermissions(context: Context, vararg permissions: String): Boolean {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && permissions != null) {
                for (permission in permissions) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }

    private lateinit var mMapView: MapView
    private var hMap: HuaweiMap? = null
    private var mMarker: Marker? = null
    private var mCircle: Circle? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "map onCreate:")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (!hasPermissions(this, *RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE)
        }

        // get mapView by layout view
        mMapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        var mapViewBundle: Bundle? = null
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY)
        }
        // please replace "Your API key" with api_key field value in
        // agconnect-services.json if the field is null.
        MapsInitializer.setApiKey("MyKEY ends ==")
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle)

        // get map by async method
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this@MainActivity)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(map: HuaweiMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: ")

        // after call getMapAsync method ,we can get HuaweiMap instance in this call back method
        hMap = map
        if (hasPermissions(this, RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS[0], RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS[1])) {
            setLocationEnabled(true)
        }

        // move camera by CameraPosition param ,latlag and zoom params can set here
        val build = CameraPosition.Builder().target(LAT_LNG).zoom(10f).build()
        val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(build)
        hMap?.animateCamera(cameraUpdate)

        // mark can be add by HuaweiMap
        mMarker = hMap?.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions().position(LAT_LNG)
//            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logo))
            .clusterable(true))

        // circle can be add by HuaweiMap
        mCircle = hMap?.addCircle(CircleOptions().center(LatLng(48.793478, 2.334595)).radius(1000.0).fillColor(Color.GREEN))
        mCircle?.fillColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            setLocationEnabled(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        }
    }

    /**
     * set location enable
     *
     * @param enable true:enable, false:disable
     */
    private fun setLocationEnabled(enable: Boolean) {
        hMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = enable
        hMap?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = enable
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        var mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY)
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = Bundle()
            outState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle)
        }
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mMapView.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mMapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mMapView.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mMapView.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mMapView.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mMapView.onLowMemory()
    }
```

Maybe the problem is  on the HMS project setup, so I added 3 SHA-256 footprints I got from the Firebase project settings (or `gradle signingReport` / `keytool -list -v -keystore)`.  But also for the case I sign my debug app with a release key:

```
signingConfigs {
    create("release") {
        keyAlias = keystoreProperties.getProperty("keyAlias")
        keyPassword = keystoreProperties.getProperty("keyPassword")
        storeFile = file(keystoreProperties.getProperty("storeFile"))
        storePassword = keystoreProperties.getProperty("storePassword")
        enableV1Signing = true
        enableV2Signing = true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
    }

    getByName("debug") {
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
}
```

And added all the permissions from the demo project.